# Converting an application to use dlls. class 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class

Tags: c++, dll, templates

This seems to be a common error, but most people online choose to just ignore the warning and move on.  I do not wish to ignore the warning.

Basically, when using __declspec(dllexport) to convert a project to use dlls, the compiler has trouble dealing with templates and stl objects.  An explanation of the problem, and suggested solution are listed [here](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/VisualStudio/warningC4251.html).  I have implemented the  giant #define statement suggested for maps, to no avail.

How do you make this work!?  My code is absolutely littered with things like wchar_ts and std::maps, so hopefully a solution that doesn't involve writing something remotely complex for each class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767579/exporting-classes-containing-std-objects-vector-map-etc-from-a-dll) for a good discussion of the topic. I would suggest either of the following:

1. Use a static library
2. Hide all `template`-related types and interfaces behind non-`template` [compiler firewall](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill05.htm) or [`pimpl`](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

After fighting with the linker changes from Visual C++ 6.0, to 2003, and then to 2005, I will never `__declspec(dllexport)` anything that has a `template`, `bool`, `wchar_t`, or `time_t` in the signature again.  Actually, we just out-right stopped using DLLs altogether.  Life is so much simpler now ;)