# VS unit tests in DLL forces to declspec(dllexport)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I wrote a DLL with `inline` implementations. I'm pretty new to Unit Tests in C++, so I added some as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-cpp-dlls?view=vs-2019#projectRef) and they just worked perfectly fine. Assertions were reacting correctly etc.

After extracting the methods in their `.cpp` for reasons, I learned that the class has to be exported (LNK2019, LNK2001).  Or at least the methods which should be able to be tested. But exporting methods expecting fe. `std::string` or STL containers as an argument, or even members of another class causes trouble with C4251, what I wanted to avoid with #4 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22054743/5811471) (TL;DR export everything else as well - does not work: C2242).

It's possible to ignore the C4251 but then the tests are failing with an C000005 exception and the following stack trace:

```
Error Message:    Exception Code: C0000005 Stack Trace:
        at std::allocator<char>::deallocate() in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0:line 573
        at std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate() in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
12.0\vc\include\xmemory0:line 859
        at std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>
::_Tidy() in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xstring:line 2284
        at std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>
::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >() in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
12.0\vc\include\xstring:line 992
```

But that evolved already in directions where I never wanted to go. Is there any solution for my issue? Like test project config or sth.? Do I have to change the test framework?