# std::vector needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'X<T> warning

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to make my library exportable as a DLL but I'm getting a lot of these warnings for one specific class that uses std::vector:

```
template <typename T>
class AGUI_CORE_DECLSPEC AguiEvent {
    typedef void (*AguiCallbackFptr)(T arg, AguiWidget* sender);
std::vector<AguiCallbackFptr> events;
public:
    void call(AguiWidget* sender, T arg) const;
    void addHandler(AguiCallbackFptr proc);
    void removeHandler(AguiCallbackFptr proc);
    void removeHandler();
    AguiEvent();
};
```

I get warnings like these:

> Warning   57  warning C4251:
>   'AguiEvent::events' : class
>   'std::vector<_Ty>' needs to have
>   dll-interface to be used by clients of
>   class 'AguiEvent'

I tried to find how to do this properly but MSDN's documentation is very Windows Only, and I need this to be cross platform so that it only does MS specific stuff when AGUI_CORE_DECLSPEC is in fact defined.

What should I do to get rid of these warnings?

Thanks

Comment: Related Core Issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767579/exporting-classes-containing-std-objects-vector-map-etc-from-a-dll

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Exporting from a DLL is platform-specific. You will have to [fix this for Windows](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/168/Q168958/) (basically use `declspec(dllexport/dllimport)` on the instantiated class template) and encapsulate the required code in your Windows-specific preprocessor macro.

My experience is that exporting STL classes from DLLs on Windows is fraught with pain, generally I try to design the interface such that this is not needed.

Comment: Any insight on why I am still getting this error with respect to private class variables?  The class is exported, but I would expect private methods and objects to not trip this warning. . .

Comment: Probably because the size of the privates impacts on the size of the exported class. It's not part of the public interface in that it's not directly accessible, but still forms part of it if it's in an exported class as a member by value. Try holding it by pointer or hiding behind a pimpl. (All of this is just a guess).

Comment: link broken again

Comment: I cannot find the content - it looks like it is really gone this time. Replaced it with a cached copy.

Answer (score 41):

One fix is relying on dynamic allocation/deallocation of the STL structures. So:

```
class EXPORTED ExportedClass
{
private:
    std::vector<int> *_integers;
public:
    ExportedClass()
    {
        _integers = new std::vector<int>();
    }
    ~ExportedClass()
    {
        delete _integers;
    }
};
```

won't give any warning and it's more safe in case you are distributing the same binary (the dll) that has to be used with different version of the compiler that may has different versions of the STL. In this way you have 100% guarantee that `sizeof(ExportedClass)` is always the same.

Comment: I guess unique_ptr could be used in this case as well? To get rid of the new and delet, I mean.

Comment: @AxP It could be used but you could have similar problems when distributing a shared library compiled with a c++ standard library that is ABI incompatible on shared pointers than the one present on the target system

Answer (score 13):

You could just export the members, which the dll-clients need to access. To do this remove the export declaration from the class declaration and add it to each individual member function you want to export.

**EDIT:**

In your case you should probably not try to export the class (leave out AGUI_CORE_DECLSPEC) since it is a template class. Provide all methods in your header as inline and it will work.

If you do not want this, some compilers provide a special way to export template classes. But you will have to specify the template parameter for this.

Comment: I only had problems with private exports and I declspec'ed the whole class. Your advice did it! I then declspec'ed the methods explicitly in the header file and it worked.

Comment: Yes, this will generally work, unless your class has a vtable/rtti enabled (by using dynamic_casts involving it), in which case you're forced to export the entire class (if building with G++11 for example), using `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`. This creates huge problems, if you want your code to also compile with MSVC, because it starts spewing those C4251 warnings, and all that i could figure out was to either make all members raw pointers, or use `#pragma warning(suppress: 4251)` on the members.

Comment: And if you end up suppressing these warnings, make sure that any size changes in the members are accompanied with a new major version release of your software, to account for potential headaches if DLL versions get mixed up in the future

Answer (score 1):

The usual method of dealing with platform specific stuff like this is to try and restrict all platform specific settings to a handful of low level files/classes, and then use #defines and #ifdef/#ifndef preprocessor directives to add/replace platform specific variations.

To effectively implement this, you may need an abstraction layer. For example a production system I worked on in the 1990s had a "File System" library. This presented a common interface to the applications and production code, but had to rely on a few platform-specific files. As well as making it easier to compile and maintain, it also made it easier to port to new platforms. A new file hardware vendor or OS flavour? Simply add the settings to the include files and add new directives accordingly.