# exporting class in C++ DLL gives warning while compiling

Tags: c++, dll

I found a IPC Library online which after compiling it will become ".lib", so i tried converting it to DLL instead of using .lib, but after declaring exports on the features i need to export the VS Express compiler gave a warning stated

> 'PipeTransport::buf_': class 'std::vector>' needs > to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class

The EXPORT definition

```
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

This is the code exported...

```
class EXPORT PipeTransport : public PipeWin {
public:
  static const size_t kBufferSz = 4096;

  size_t Send(const void* buf, size_t sz) {
    return Write(buf, sz) ? ipc::RcOK : ipc::RcErrTransportWrite;
  }

  char* Receive(size_t* size);

private:
  IPCCharVector buf_;//The Line giving error
};
```

The Library link is [here](https://github.com/noobshow/simple-ipc-lib/tree/master/src)

The Header file giving error is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noobshow/simple-ipc-lib/master/src/pipe_win.h)

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145605/stdvector-needs-to-have-dll-interface-to-be-used-by-clients-of-class-xt-war) , but can't get it to work coz i don't understand much of it as i'm new to C++(Totally noob).

Comment: The answer is returned in the first result if you google your error. Why do we have to google something for you?

Comment: Maybe it showed that result in your location, Google didn't show this here to me...
And, thanks for the Suggestion... That was exactly what i wanted to know how to do... Insantiating a class...
Thanks once again

Answer (score -1):

The C way to export a class object will be like that but I don't know how to export class in DLL

```
Here your DLL
class AbstractClass
{
public:
    virtual void somefunction() = 0;
}

//Inherite from this class
class MyClass : public AbstractClass
{
    virtual void somefucntion(){/*implement*/}
}

//Create your export object
MyClass* myObject = NULL;

//Create some EXPORT define to make it easy when you declare function
#define EXPORT_DLL __declspec(dllexport)

//Declare function
extern "C" EXPORT_DLL void* myExportedFunction ();

//Implement
EXPORT_DLL void* myExportedFunction ()
{
    if(myObject == NULL)
        myObject = new MyClass();
    return myObject;
}
```

And now from exterior of your function you can call this function like that. Sure you need to load your dll, your function and other things, here i just pass these step and show you only how to use this code.

```
//You must have a declaration of your abstract class in exterior of dll
AbstractClass* dllObjet = NULL;

dllObject = myExportedFunction()

//And now you can use it
dllObject->somefucntion();
```

Comment: Wrong. You can have classess exported out of DLLs.

Comment: Oh my bad, i always thinked that it was not possible, and i looked at google and you are right, sorry for that, I modify my answer

Comment: What about if i don't need the classes?
Should i follow this method to simplify the function name instead of all this :: Class bits?