# Passing reference to STL vector over dll boundary

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake

I have a nice library for managing files that needs to return specific lists of strings. Since the only code I'm ever going to use it with is going to be C++ (and Java but that's using C++ through JNI) I decided to use vector from the standard libraries. The library functions look a little bit like this (where FILE_MANAGER_EXPORT is platform-defined export requirement):

```
extern "C" FILE_MANAGER_EXPORT void get_all_files(vector<string> &files)
{
    files.clear();
    for (vector<file_struct>::iterator i = file_structs.begin(); i != file_structs.end(); ++i)
    {
        files.push_back(i->full_path);
    }
}
```

The reason I used the vector as a reference instead of return value is an attempt to keep memory allocations sane and because windows was really unhappy me having extern "C" around a c++ return type (who knows why, my understanding is that all extern "C" does is prevent name mangling in the compiler). Anyway, the code for using this with other c++ is generally as follows:

```
#if defined _WIN32
    #include <Windows.h>
    #define GET_METHOD GetProcAddress
    #define OPEN_LIBRARY(X) LoadLibrary((LPCSTR)X)
    #define LIBRARY_POINTER_TYPE HMODULE
    #define CLOSE_LIBRARY FreeLibrary
#else
    #include <dlfcn.h>
    #define GET_METHOD dlsym
    #define OPEN_LIBRARY(X) dlopen(X, RTLD_NOW)
    #define LIBRARY_POINTER_TYPE void*
    #define CLOSE_LIBRARY dlclose
#endif

typedef void (*GetAllFilesType)(vector<string> &files);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    LIBRARY_POINTER_TYPE manager = LOAD_LIBRARY("library.dll"); //Just an example, actual name is platform-defined too
    GetAllFilesType get_all_files_pointer = (GetAllFilesType) GET_METHOD(manager, "get_all_files");
    vector<string> files;
    (*get_all_files_pointer)(files);

    // ... Do something with files ...

    return 0;
}
```

The library is compiled through cmake using add_library(file_manager SHARED file_manager.cpp). The program is compiled in a separate cmake project using add_executable(file_manager_command_wrapper command_wrapper.cpp). There are no compile flags specified for either, just those commands.

Now the program works perfectly fine in both mac and linux. The problem is windows. When run, I get this error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> ...
>
> Expression: _pFirstBlock == _pHead

This, I have found out and kind of understand, is because of separate memory heaps between executables and loaded dlls. I believe this occurs when memory is allocated in one heap and deallocated in the other. The problem is, for the life of me, I can't figure what is going wrong. The memory is allocated in the executable and passed as a reference to the dll function, values are added via the reference, and then those are processed and finally deallocated back in the executable.

I would reveal more code if I could but intellectual property at my company states I can't, so all of the above code is merely examples.

Anyone with more knowledge of the subject able to help me understand this error, and point me in the right direction to debug and fix it? I'm unfortunately not able to use a windows machine for debugging since I develop on linux, then commit any changes to a gerrit server which triggers builds and tests through jenkins. I have access to the output console upon compile and test.

I did consider using non-stl types, copying the vector in c++ to a char**, but the memory allocation was a nightmare and I was struggling to get it working nicely on linux let  alone windows and it's horrible multiple heaps.

EDIT: It definitely crashes as soon as the files vector goes out of scope. My current thought is that the strings put into the vector are allocated on the dll heap and deallocated on the executable heap. If this is the case, can anyone enlighten me as to a better solution?

Comment: 1. Passing by value is fine, c++0x and up has move semantix that will make all the memory copying "sane".
2. This is a guess, but you are probably just experiencing "dll hell". The best way to get around it is to export the STL class, see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767579/exporting-classes-containing-std-objects-vector-map-etc-from-a-dll]

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I was doing that at first but was getting the same error. That is what prompted me to move to passing by reference in an attempt to keep memory allocations/deallocations all on the executable.

Answer (score 16):

Your main problem is that passing C++ types across DLL boundaries is difficult.
You need the following

1. Same compiler
2. Same standard library
3. Same settings for exceptions
4. In Visual C++ you need same version of the compiler
5. In Visual C++ you need same Debug/Release configuration
6. In Visual C++ you need same Iterator debug level

And so on

If that is what you want, I wrote a header-only library called cppcomponents https://github.com/jbandela/cppcomponents that provides the easiest way to do it in C++.
You need a compiler with strong support for C++11. Gcc 4.7.2 or 4.8 will work. Visual C++ 2013 preview also works.

I will walk you through using cppcomponents to solve your problem.

1. `git clone https://github.com/jbandela/cppcomponents.git` in the directory of your choice. We will refer to the directory where you ran this command as `localgit`
2. Create a file called `interfaces.hpp`. In this file you will define the interface that can be used across compilers.

Enter the following

```
#include <cppcomponents/cppcomponents.hpp>

using cppcomponents::define_interface;
using cppcomponents::use;
using cppcomponents::runtime_class;
using cppcomponents::use_runtime_class;
using cppcomponents::implement_runtime_class;
using cppcomponents::uuid;
using cppcomponents::object_interfaces;

struct IGetFiles:define_interface<uuid<0x633abf15,0x131e,0x4da8,0x933f,0xc13fbd0416cd>>{

    std::vector<std::string> GetFiles();

    CPPCOMPONENTS_CONSTRUCT(IGetFiles,GetFiles);


};

inline std::string FilesId(){return "Files!Files";}
typedef runtime_class<FilesId,object_interfaces<IGetFiles>> Files_t;
typedef use_runtime_class<Files_t> Files;
```

Next create an implementation. To do this create `Files.cpp`.

Add the following code

```
#include "interfaces.h"


struct ImplementFiles:implement_runtime_class<ImplementFiles,Files_t>{
  std::vector<std::string> GetFiles(){
    std::vector<std::string> ret = {"samplefile1.h", "samplefile2.cpp"};
    return ret;

  }

  ImplementFiles(){}


};

CPPCOMPONENTS_DEFINE_FACTORY();
```

Finally here is the file to use the above. Create `UseFiles.cpp`

Add the following code

```
#include "interfaces.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  Files f;
  auto vec_files = f.GetFiles();
  for(auto& name:vec_files){
      std::cout << name << "\n";
    }

}
```

Now you can compile. Just to show we are compatible across compilers, we will use `cl` the Visual C++ compiler to compile `UseFiles.cpp` into `UseFiles.exe`. We will use Mingw Gcc to compile `Files.cpp` into `Files.dll`

`cl /EHsc UseFiles.cpp /I localgit\cppcomponents`

where `localgit` is the directory in which you ran `git clone` as described above

`g++ -std=c++11 -shared -o Files.dll Files.cpp -I localgit\cppcomponents`

There is no link step. Just make sure `Files.dll` and `UseFiles.exe` are in the same directory.

Now run the executable with `UseFiles`

cppcomponents will also work on Linux. The main change is when you compile the exe, you need to add `-ldl` to the flag, and when you compile the .so file, you need to add `-fPIC` to the flags.

If you have further questions, let me know.

Comment: You wrote: *"...And so on. If that is what you want, I wrote a header-only library called cppcomponents..."* Did you mean "If you don't want to ensure all this then..."? Isn't your library meant to avoid needing all of this and *allow* interoperability?

Answer (score 8):

Everybody seems to be hung up on the infamous DLL-compiler-incompatibility issue here, but I think you are right about this being related to the heap allocations. I suspect what is happening is that the vector (allocated in main exe's heap space) contains strings allocated in the DLL's heap space. When the vector goes out of scope and is deallocated, it's also attempting to deallocate the strings - and all this is happening on the .exe side, which causes the crash.

I have two instinctive suggestions:

1. Wrap each string in a `std::unique_ptr`. It includes a 'deleter' which handles the deallocation of its contents when the unique_ptr goes out of scope. When the unique_ptr is created on the DLL side, so is its deleter. So when the vector goes out of scope and the destructors of its contents are called, the strings will be deallocated by their DLL-bound deleters and no heap conflict occurs.

   ```
   extern "C" FILE_MANAGER_EXPORT void get_all_files(vector<unique_ptr<string>>& files)
   {
       files.clear();
       for (vector<file_struct>::iterator i = file_structs.begin(); i != file_structs.end(); ++i)
       {
           files.push_back(unique_ptr<string>(new string(i->full_path)));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Keep the vector on the DLL side and just return a reference to it. You can pass the reference across the DLL boundary:

   ```
   vector<string> files;

   extern "C" FILE_MANAGER_EXPORT vector<string>& get_all_files()
   {
       files.clear();
       for (vector<file_struct>::iterator i = file_structs.begin(); i != file_structs.end(); ++i)
       {
           files.push_back(i->full_path);
       }
       return files;
   }
   ```

---

Semi-related: [“Downcasting” `unique_ptr<Base>` to `unique_ptr<Derived>` (across DLL boundary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived):

Comment: How does option #2 work? I have a very limited understanding of all of this, but I thought a reason for DLL boundary issues is because even given the same C++ source code, a compiler can organize a class’s data in different ways. My question is: in #2, when I access an element of the returned vector using the [] operator in the EXE, does it use the DLL’s [] code or its own? If its own, couldn’t that be wrong?

Answer (score 6):

> The memory is allocated in the executable and passed as a reference to the dll function, values are added via the reference, and then those are processed and finally deallocated back in the executable.

Adding values if there is no space left (capacity) means a reallocation, so the old will be deallocated & a new will be allocated. That'll be done by the library's std::vector::push_back function, which will use the library's memory allocator.

Other than that, you've got the obvious compile-settings-must-match-exactly and of course they are kind of compiler-specifics dependant. You've most likely got to keep them synced in terms of compiles.

Answer (score 4):

The vector there uses the default std::allocator, which uses ::operator new for its allocation.

The problem is, when the vector is used in the DLL's context, it is compiled with that DLL's vector code, which knows about the ::operator new provided by that DLL.

The code in the EXE will try to use the EXE's ::operator new.

I bet the reason this works on Mac/Linux and not on Windows is because Windows requires all symbols be resolved at compile time.

For example, you may have seen Visual Studio give an error saying something like "Unresolved external symbol." It means "You told me this function named foo() exists, but I can't find it anywhere."

This is not the same as what Mac/Linux does. It requires all symbols be resolved at load time. What this means is you can compile a .so with a missing ::operator new. And your program can load in your .so and provide its ::operator new to the .so, allowing it to be resolved. By default, all symbols are exported in GCC, and so ::operator new will be exported by the program and potentially loaded in by your .so.

There is an interesting thing here, where Mac/Linux allows circular dependencies. The program could rely on a symbol that is provided by the .so, and that same .so might rely on a symbol provided by the program. Circular dependencies are a terrible thing and so I really like that the Windows method forces you to not do this.

But, that said, the real problem is that you are trying to use C++ objects across boundaries. That is definitely a mistake. It will ONLY work if the compiler used in the DLL and the EXE is the same, with the same settings. The 'extern "C"' may attempt to prevent name mangling (not sure what it does for non-C-types like std::vector). But it doesn't change the fact that the other side may have a totally different implementation of std::vector.

Generally speaking, if it is passed across boundaries like that, you want it to be in a plain old C type. If it is things like ints and simple types, things aren't so difficult. In your case, you probably want to pass an array of char*. Which means you still need to be careful about memory management.

The DLL/.so should manage its own memory.
So the function might be like this:

```
Foo *bar = nullptr;
int barCount = 0;
getFoos( bar, &barCount );
// use your foos
releaseFoos(bar);
```

The drawback is that you will have extra code to convert things to C-sharable types at the boundaries. And sometimes this leaks into your implementation in order to speed up the implementation.

But the benefit is now people can use any language and any compiler version and any settings to write a DLL for you. And you are more careful about proper memory management and dependencies.

I know it is extra work. But that is the proper way to do things across boundaries.

Comment: The DLL being created is compiled at the same time as the executable within the same CMAKE project, so the compilers and all settings are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs because dynamic (shared) libraries in MS languages use a different heap than the main executable. Creating a string in the DLL or updating the vector that causes a reallocation will cause this issue.

The simplest fix for THIS issue is to change the library to a static lib (not certain how one makes CMAKE do that) because then all the allocations will occur in the executable and on a single heap.   Of course then you have all of the static library compatibility issues of MS C++ which make your library less attractive.

The requirements at the top of John Bandela's response are all similar to those for the static library implementation.

Another solution is to implement the interface in the header (thereby compiled in the application space) and have those methods call pure functions with a C interface provided in the DLL.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running into binary compatibility issues.  On windows, if you want to use C++ interfaces between DLLs you have to make sure that a lot of things are in order, for ex.

- All DLLs involved must be built with the same version of the visual studio compiler
- All DLLs have to have link the same version of the C++ runtime (in most versions of VS this is the Runtime Library setting under Configuration -> C++ -> Code Generation in the project properties)
- Iterator debugging settings have to be the same for all builds (this is part of the reason you can't mix Release and Debug DLL's)

That's not an exhaustive list by any stretch unfortunately :(

Comment: Well the build is automated through cmake unfortunately, although the compiler is from visual studio, so I don't have any settings like that. It literally only uses the add_library and add_executable commands with no flags specified. I'll look into cmake with visual studio and see

Comment: A little bit of research led me to using the /MD flag to make sure the C++ runtime is dynamically linked. Added this to the cmake project with `set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} /MD")`. No luck so far though

Comment: Did you add this flag only to the shared library, or to the executable also?

Comment: For the entire cmake project which compiles both the shared library and the executable

Answer (score 0):

My - partial - solution has been to implement all default constructors in the dll frame, so explicitly add (impelement) copy, assignment operator and even move constructors, depending on your program. This will cause the correct ::new to be called (assuming you specify __declspec(dllexport)). Include destructor implementations as well for matching deletes.
Do not include any implementation code in a (dll) header file.
I still get warnings about using non dll-interfaced classes (with stl containers) as base for dll-interfaced classes, but it works. This is using VS2013 RC for native code, on, obviously, windows.

Comment: This will still explode if any exported functions cause a realloc, this is not a solution