# How to handle return of Abstract Objects

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, abstract-class, return-value

I'm facing the following situation:

```cpp
 class Base{
      virtual void Stuff() = 0;
 };

 class ConcreteA : public Base{
      void Stuff() {};
 };

 class ConcreteB : public Base{
      void Stuff() {};
 };

 class Context {
      Base exec() {
           ConcreteA conc_a();
           return a;
      }
 };
```

Of course the compiler gives me an error since `Base` is abstract. However, I'd need that `exec()` return a Base type. I know that I can make the compiler happy using pointers or references, but since the object ConcreteA is created in `exec()`, returning by value is the best way to avoid dangling references or pointer with undefined ownership.

Is there a way to avoid using pointers or references to handle this kind of situations?

Comment: No there's no way of avoiding references or pointers, if you want to return the "base" type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a perfect, simple use case for `std::unique_ptr`. Here is a C++14 example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Base{
public:
      virtual ~Base() {}
      virtual void Stuff() = 0;
};

class ConcreteA : public Base{
      void Stuff() { std::cout << "ConcreteA::Stuff\n"; };
};

class ConcreteB : public Base{
      void Stuff() { std::cout << "ConcreteB::Stuff\n";};
};

class Context {
public:
      std::unique_ptr<Base> exec() {
           return std::make_unique<ConcreteA>();
      }
};

int main()
{
    Context c;
    auto base_ptr = c.exec();
    base_ptr->Stuff();
}
```

Memory is automatically deleted when `base_ptr` in `main` goes out of scope.

Note that I also made the `Base` destructor virtual. Perhaps you just left it out in your code example for the sake of brevity, but its importance should be stressed, and I think it should be kept even in short example code.

Comment: It might be worth drawing attention to the importance of adding the virtual destructor.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Right. I added something to the answer.

Comment: @Mike Seymour What do you mean exactly? The unique_ptr should be automatically deleted when Context goes out of scope, am I wrong?

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh: The `unique_ptr` will delete the `ConcreteA` object via a pointer to `Base`. That gives undefined behaviour unless `Base` has a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh: As Mike correctly says, it is undefined behaviour to delete (or in the case of `std::unique_ptr`, let someone else automatically delete) an object of derived type through a base pointer if the base destructor is not virtual. Try to make `Base::~Base` non-virtual and add `~ConcreteA() { std::cout << "~ConcreteA\n"; }`. You will very likely see one possible outcome of undefined behaviour, but the program could really do anything it wants.

Comment: What if after calling `exec` I need the concrete type in the main function? without the unique_ptr the substitution is made by the compiler, but not in this case

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh: Not sure what you mean. The compiler will not substitute a base type for a derived type. You'd need a `dynamic_cast` for that. But that's often already a sign of class-design errors. Why return `Base` if you will specifically need `ConcreteA` later on?

Comment: @Christian Hackl Because actually I have an AsbtractContext class. ContextA that produces ConcreteA and ContextB that produces ConcreteB. Afterwards, other classes will handle ContextA and other ContextB, so they should be able to access to the methods of ConcreteA and B.

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh: Are you talking about covariant return types? I don't think you need them in your example. Just have all methods return `std::unique_ptr<Base>`. As I said, I don't see the problem. As long as you don't need `dynamic_cast`, everything should be pretty straight-forward, unless I completely misunderstand the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will re-think the architecture! Actually I'm using an Abstract Factory pattern. And in this case probably the dynamic_cast is the only way

Comment: @Gabrielecswoosh: Refactoring may be a good idea, but for reference, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived. It discusses the question of how to cast a `std::unique_ptr`.