# c++ Cast a vector of unique_ptr<Base> to unique_ptr<Derived> where derived is a template

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

I have the following situation:

`Base` is a base class.
`T` is a template that can assume any derived class of `Base`.

The underlying layer provide me data from `Base` class, that I need to convert to a specific class on the above layer (that layer where the code is written) to work on a user level.

Here is the code:

```
template <class T> class Access {
       std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> getData();        
}

template <class T>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> getData()
{
      /// Get data from below layer
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> retData; 

      retData = getDataFromBelowLayer();

      /// Now I have to cast Base to T
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> retCastData;

      for (auto &item : retData)
      {
          std::unique_ptr<T> = static_cast<T>(item); <<---- NOT WORKING
          retCastData.push_back(std::move(item));    <<---- NOT WORKING
      }

      return retCastData;
}
```

How can I efficiently cast the `vector` of `unique_ptr´s` of `Base` class received to the `vector` of `unique_ptr´s` of `T` type as shown.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: it seems like the usual `polymorphic_downcast`

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived).

Comment: The above code clearly isn't the code that is not working, as it has errors on completely different lines.  Please provide actual minimal examples that demonstrate the actual problem (and your attempted solutions), and include the actual error message generated.

Comment: How do you know all of the `Base` are actually `T`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do:

```
struct Base {};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : public Base {};


template <typename T>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > getData()
{
      //add some checking:
      static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "T must be derived from Base");

      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > retData; 
      //fill it somehow

      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > retCastData;

      for (auto& item : retData)
      {
          auto t = std::unique_ptr<T>(static_cast<T*>(item.release()));   //(*)
          retCastData.push_back(std::move(t));
      }

      return retCastData;
}

int main()
{
    getData<Derived<int> >();   //or some other type than "int"
}
```

The main thing happens in the line marked with `(*)`. Here the unique-pointer is released and the returned raw pointer is downcasted to the derived class, and next inserted into the vector. (The core of this code is inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived?lq=1), but the deleter stuff is omitted here.)

Note that the fact that `Derived` is a class template does not matter at all here (beside that you have to pass `Derived</*some type*/>` instead of `Derived` to `getData`).

Comment: Is rhe `staric_assert` redundant, or overly strict?  I mean the `static_cast` will error if the types are completely unrelated?

Comment: @Yakk: good point. Yes, it is technically redundant, but of course there is still the more verbose error message.

Comment: @Yakk: ... which for me in practice is no reason to add it ... just wrote that down before the rest and it stayed there :-)

Comment: This is not exception safe. If `emplace_back` throws, the pointer that has been `release()`'d is leaked.

Comment: @T.C.: thanks for the thorough inspection. I'll made an edit which I think corrects on this (as `release()` and the `unique_ptr` constructor are both `noexcept`).