# Return a unique_ptr to polymorphic type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to be a bit safer by returning a unique_ptr from a few of my methods rather than a raw pointer. However, I am a little confused when it comes to returning a unique pointer to a polymorphic type.

How do we return a unique pointer of base class type that points to a derived class type?

Also, as a secondary question of less importance - Am I creating my derived class from a base class properly using the move constructor?

Here is my minimal example:

```
// Standard Includes
#include <exception>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class BaseResult
{
public:

    std::string m_x;

    virtual ~BaseResult() {};
};

class DerivedResult : public BaseResult
{
public:

    int m_y;

    DerivedResult()
        :
        BaseResult()
    {}

    DerivedResult(const DerivedResult & rhs)
        :
        BaseResult(rhs)
      , m_y       (rhs.m_y)
    {}

    DerivedResult(DerivedResult && rhs)
        :
        BaseResult(std::move(rhs))
      , m_y(rhs.m_y)
    {}

    DerivedResult(BaseResult && rhs)
        :
        BaseResult(std::move(rhs))
        , m_y()
    {
    }

    ~DerivedResult() {}
};

class BaseCalc
{
public:

    virtual ~BaseCalc() {}

    virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseResult> Calc() const
    {
        std::unique_ptr<BaseResult> result(new BaseResult);
        result->m_x = "Base Calced";

        return result;
    }

};

class DerivedCalc : public BaseCalc
{
public:

    virtual ~DerivedCalc() {}

    virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseResult> Calc() const
    {
        // I need to rely on the base calculations to get the fields relevant to the base
        std::unique_ptr<BaseResult> baseResult = BaseCalc::Calc();

        // However, I want to perform my addtional calculation relevant to derived, here.
        std::unique_ptr<DerivedResult> result(new DerivedResult(std::move(*baseResult)));
        result->m_y = 2;

        /* Results in error
        return result;
        */
        return std::move(result); // Is this how we do it?
    }
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    DerivedCalc calculator;
    std::unique_ptr<BaseResult> temp = calculator.Calc();

    // Cast - Got this part from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/
    std::unique_ptr<DerivedResult> actualResult;

    if (DerivedResult * cast = dynamic_cast<DerivedResult *>(temp.get()))
    {
        actualResult = std::unique_ptr<DerivedResult>(cast, std::move(temp.get_deleter()));
        temp.release();
    }
    else
    {
        std::exception("Failed to cast to DerivedResult");
    }

    std::string x = actualResult->m_x;
    int y = actualResult->m_y;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AnonMail Can you elaborate please? Do you mean the missing `virtual` destructor?

Comment: @anon Ok, can you be more descriptive? Do you mean, that's not how you inherit in general, or is your concern over the move constructor from base? What would you change?

Comment: This doesn't build under vs2017, interestingly. The line where you set `actualResult` complains that the arguments don't match any constructor of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Rook I built using 2010. I am unfortuantly forced to use that on this project. I do wonder why 2017 complains though. I got that cast portion from another stack overflow question, so it will have to be updated if it no longer works. We'll then have the additional complexity of how to assign base unique ptr to derived unique ptr

Comment: you should not move on return statement, rather than that everything else looks fine to me.

Comment: @Slava if I do not then I get a compiler error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>

I also thought the move wasn't required, but that the compiler automatically did it for me. I am new to C++11 move semantics though. Having to put the move there to get it to compile spurred my question.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz seems too be compiler bug, it should work without explicit move

Comment: Could be, 2010 is a piece of garbage. I'll grab 2017 just to see if it compiles, but I'll have to keep the move there for 2010 even if it does, as long as no one sees bad side effects from doing so. Are there any?

Comment: Btw should `std::unique_ptr` have `dynamic_pointer_cast` and company like `std::shared_ptr` does?

Comment: @Slava What would such `dynamic_pointer_cast` return? Another `unique_ptr` pointing to the same object? Hello, double destruction. Raw pointer? Then it's no different from `dynamic_cast<AnotherType*>(myPtr.get())`

Comment: @Slava No, it wouldn't and shouldn't compile without `std::move`: [Demo](http://rextester.com/MYRI24373). There is a special dispensation to treat the object in a `return` statement as an rvalue, but only "when the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met" (**[class.copy]/32**); and those are met "in a `return` statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object ... with **the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type**" (emphasis mine). This holds in `BaseCalc::Calc`, but not in `DerivedCalc::Calc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your first question, "How do we return a unique pointer of base class type that points to a derived class type?" (note that std::make_unique requires c++14):

```
class DerivedCalc : public BaseCalc
{
public:

    virtual ~DerivedCalc() {}

    virtual std::unique_ptr<BaseResult> Calc() const
    {
        // I need to rely on the base calculations to get the fields relevant to the base
        std::unique_ptr<BaseResult> baseResult = BaseCalc::Calc();

        // However, I want to perform my addtional calculation relevant to derived, here.
        std::unique_ptr<BaseResult> result(std::make_unique<DerivedResult>(std::move(*baseResult)));
        DerivedResult& derived = static_cast<DerivedResult&>(*result);
        derived.m_y = 2;

        return result;
    }
};
```

For your 2nd question, "Am I creating my derived class from a base class properly using the move constructor?", your version works, but you can also move the derived data field for optimal performance:

```
class DerivedResult : public BaseResult
{
    ...
    DerivedResult(DerivedResult && rhs)
        :
        BaseResult(std::move(rhs))
        , m_y(std::move(rhs.m_y))
    {}
    ...
};
```