# “Downcasting” unique_ptr<Base> to unique_ptr<Derived> with unique_ptr<Data> in Derived

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

[“Downcasting” unique_ptr< Base > to unique_ptr< Derived >](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived) offer an elegent solution to downcasting unique_ptr. It works in most of time. But when the Derived contains unique_ptr, something go wrong:

```
template<typename Derived, typename Base, typename Del>
std::unique_ptr<Derived, Del> 
static_unique_ptr_cast( std::unique_ptr<Base, Del>&& p )
{
    auto d = static_cast<Derived *>(p.release());
    return std::unique_ptr<Derived, Del>(d, std::move(p.get_deleter()));
} 

struct Data
{
   int data;
};

struct Base
{
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived() 
        : data(std::make_unique<Data>())

    std::unique_ptr<Data> data;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base = std::make_unique<Derived>();

    auto data = static_unique_ptr_case<Derived>(std::move(base))->data; // compile error

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to fix the problem?

**Eidt:**

fix the typos and

**@Igor Tandetnik** give a solution

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> base = std::make_unique<Derived>();

//auto& data = static_unique_ptr_case<Derived>(std::move(base))->data; // compile error

auto derived = static_unique_ptr_case<Derived>(std::move(base));

auto& data = derived->data;

return 0;
```

Comment: Apart from typos (`Derived` constructor not being properly defined, missing `;`, etc), the problem is because `std::unique_ptr` has an explicitly `delete`d copy constructor, and the offending error is because of an attempt to copy construct a `std::unique_ptr<Data>`.    Without knowing WHY you expect copy constructing a `std::unique_ptr` to work - since by design it does not - nobody can really help you.

Comment: Your program boils down to `std::unique_ptr<Data> data; auto derived = data;` The failure has nothing to do with `static_unique_ptr_cast`. After fixing numerous obvious typos, [this code compiles](https://ideone.com/W6Ds0p)

Comment: @ Igor Tandetnik Thank you. I see.

Answer (score 1):

The online documentation states this about [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

> The class satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but not the requirements of either CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable.

So you cannot copy construct or copy assign a `unique_ptr` as you are trying to do in the line:

```
auto derived = static_unique_ptr_cast<Derived>(std::move(base))->data; // compile error
```