# How to call superclass method in multiple-inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have a class `C` that inherits both from `Ai` and `B`. `A` and `B` are unrelated. This is all best explained with the code below. In `main()`, I have a variable `a` defined as `std::unique_ptr<A>`, but initialized with `C`. I cannot change this definition.

My question is, given `a` defined like this, how can I call functions defined in `B` or `C` or `Ai` correctly?

```
#include <memory>

class A 
{ 
public: 
  void fun_a() {}
}; 
  
class B 
{ 
public: 
  void fun_b() {}
}; 

class Ai : public A
{ 
public:
    void fun_ai() {}
}; 
  
class C: public Ai, public B
{ 
public:
    void fun_c() {}
}; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    // I cannot change the following definition:
    std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<C>();
    
    a->fun_a();
    //a->fun_b(); // How ?
    //a->fun_c(); // How ?
    //a->fun_ai(); // How ?
    
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: One word: downcasting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Downcasting" unique\_ptr<Base> to unique\_ptr<Derived>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `static_cast` to `C*`:

```
static_cast<C*>(a.get())->fun_b();
static_cast<C*>(a.get())->fun_c();
static_cast<C*>(a.get())->fun_ai();
```

or you could make it polymorphic:

```
class A { 
public: 
    virtual ~A() = default;
    void fun_a() { std::cout << "fun_a\n"; }
};
```

and then `dynamic_cast`:

```
dynamic_cast<B*>(a.get())->fun_b();
dynamic_cast<C*>(a.get())->fun_c();
dynamic_cast<Ai*>(a.get())->fun_ai();
```

Note: `dynamic_cast`s to pointer types may fail and return `nullptr` so, if there's any doubt, check the return value.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8PK1Pc)

Comment: If you're using a base class pointer to address a derived class instance, surely all of the classes in the chain should contain virtual destructors as a matter of principle?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Re `dynamic_cast` very true, I added a note. If I should `static_cast` from `A*` to `B*` I'd need to go via `C` so it's pretty similar to the first option I guess.

Comment: @Den-Jason Only if the instance were to be destroyed through a `B*` can I see a problem (and I don't see that happening). The rest of the destructors are already `virtual` automatically. Hmm, come to think of it, even destroyed via a `B*` should it be ok.

Comment: OK - so at least the `A` class should contain a virtual destructor; the OPs code as it stands could cause undefined behaviour: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

Comment: and (a bit clearer) https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/OOP52-CPP.+Do+not+delete+a+polymorphic+object+without+a+virtual+destructor

Comment: @Den-Jason Yes, `A` should have a `virtual` destructor since a `C` is being destroyed through an `A*`.  Now, OP:s classes don't have any member variables or virtual methods so I'm not sure if it's UB or not. It's not nice anyway :)

Comment: Thank you Ted, that worked well. Yes, I do have member variables and virtual methods as well both in A and B. Ai and C do not. Should I define virtual constructors and destructors for A and B ?

Comment: @N.R. Great, you're welcome! When you may need to destroy something through a base class pointer (as in this case), make the base class destructor `virtual`. There is no such thing as `virtual` constructors though.