# Casting to another class in C++

Tags: c++, class, casting, unique-ptr, dynamic-cast

I have problem to cast one class to another which inheritance from the first one.
This is my function:

```
unique_ptr<game_state<int>> new_state = c4->make_move(column);
```

And now I want to overwrite it so I've tried like this:

```
c4 = dynamic_cast<unique_ptr<connect4<int>>*>(new_state);
```

but it don't work. That's how I declare my c4 object:

```
unique_ptr<connect4<int>> c4;
```

and my class:

```
template <typename Move>
class connect4 : public game_state<typename Move>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you need `unique_ptr` to work with, why not just `connect4<int> *c4 = dynamic_cast<connect4<int>*>(new_state.get());`? There is `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` for `std::shared_ptr`, but AFAIK there is no equivalent for `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“Downcasting” unique_ptr<Base> to unique_ptr<Derived>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived)

Comment: I now realised that better for me is to have c4 declared like this: `connect4<int> c4;`, cause my function work with it. So is it possible to cast `unique_ptr<game_state<int>>` to `connect4<int>`  ?

Comment: This design doesn't look good at all. If you always need to downcast the result of a method, then the method is not placed in the right class and doesn't return the right type.