# CRTP with abstract interface, dynamic_cast working but dynamic_pointer_cast does not

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, crtp

I'm considering the basic example of CRTP in Wikipedia

```
#include <memory>

// Base class has a pure virtual function for cloning
class AbstractShape {
 public:
  virtual ~AbstractShape() = default;
  virtual std::unique_ptr<AbstractShape> clone() const = 0;
};

// This CRTP class implements clone() for Derived
template <typename Derived>
class Shape : public AbstractShape {
 public:
  std::unique_ptr<AbstractShape> clone() const override {
    return std::make_unique<Derived>(static_cast<Derived const&>(*this));
  }

 protected:
  // We make clear Shape class needs to be inherited
  Shape() = default;
  Shape(const Shape&) = default;
  Shape(Shape&&) = default;
};

class Square : public Shape<Square> {};
```

In a main() function, the following compiles

```
Square sq1;
std::unique_ptr<AbstractShape> sq2 = sq1.clone();
dynamic_cast<Square*>(sq2.get());
```

But the following does not

```
Square sq1;
std::unique_ptr<AbstractShape> sq2 = sq1.clone();
std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Square>(sq2.get());
```

and the compiler gives the error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘dynamic_pointer_cast<Square>(std::unique_ptr<AbstractShape>::pointer)’
   std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Square>(sq2.get());
                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:81,
                 from /home/mario/dev/bayesmix/test/crtp_aux.h:1,
                 from /home/mario/dev/bayesmix/test/crtp.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1571:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class _Tp1, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp> std::__shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp> std::dynamic_pointer_cast(const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp2, _Lp>&)
     dynamic_pointer_cast(const __shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>& __r) noexcept
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1571:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/mario/dev/bayesmix/test/crtp.cc:37:46: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::__shared_ptr<_Tp2, _Lp>’ and ‘std::unique_ptr<AbstractShape>::pointer {aka AbstractShape*}’
   std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Square>(sq2.get());
```

Basically saying that template deduction failed. However, `Square` is not templated nor `AbstractShape`.

Comment: `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` converts smart pointers: pass `sq2` instead of `sq2.get()`. Edit: I read too fast, it's for `std::shared_ptr` exclusively as well. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21174593/3233393).

Comment: Why do you need the cast at all? Isn't there a clean way with covariant return types or simple interface-usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::shared_ptr<AbstractShape> sq2 = sq1.clone();
auto sq3 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Square>(sq2);
```

dynamic pointer cast converts shared ptrs.  The template deduction that is failing is that of the cast function.

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass an `shared_ptr` as the argument for `dynamic_pointer_cast`. However you passed a raw pointer. So I guess you have a couple of options.

1. Just use the first approach (if you do not intend to turn it into a `shared_ptr`)
2. Convert `sq2` to `shared_ptr` and pass it (without `.get()`)