DLLs, Classes & Memory Management
So this is more of a general question at this point, I don't have code written yet.
But when you are writing code for DLLs in C++, is the burden of memory management on the DLL or on the user ? My initial thought was to have a "factory" c-wrapper function that would be called to instantiate my object , and then there would be other wrapper functions acting as getters and setters. And finally there would be a destructor function the user could call. I'm trying to structure it to avoid memory management issues.
But is this bad practice ? Is it common practice to not use classes in DLLs to avoid this issue ? If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.
I have outlined my approach but it seems wrong to me, so I came here to see what the accepted practices are.

As the DLL and program using it (the exe) can/will have different C++ runtime library versions this make C++ memory management across module boundaries difficult.  You can't  allocate in the DLL and free memory in the Exe without helper functions for example.

Yes, that's what I understood. I would have a function the user could call that would destroy the object. Is that what you mean by helper function?

"'m trying to structure it to avoid memory management issues" -- While there is some relationship here, simply structuring your data does not avoid all memory management issues, and avoiding memory management issues does not require structuring your data. I think you are looking at an issue that does not exist, or at least misnaming it "memory management".

"My initial thought was to have a 'factory' c-wrapper function that would be called to instantiate my object" -- Why? I'm not saying this is a bad idea. Rather, I think you would benefit from delving deeper into this. What benefit is there to having a factory function over letting people use a constructor?

After some reading, I realized I wanted to avoid name mangling so I thought I would use C-wrapper functions that would instantiate the object. I didn't have the thought to just call the constructor directly, but now that you say it that does make more sense. Thanks.

You can compile your dll with the same compiler and runtime as the executable and freely allocate and free memory across dll boundaries. The undefined behavior happens when you mix the settings or possibly use an incompatible compiler.

Here is an old question about some of the issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885060/passing-reference-to-stl-vector-over-dll-boundary

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
