# Why put dllexport after class declaration will eliminate C4251 warning in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dllexport

In MSVC, When I write a class with a std::unordered_map member like below,

```
class DLLEXPORT TTT
{
    std::unordered_map<int, int> _map;
};
```

a C4251 warning is given:

```
warning C4251: 'TTT::_map' : class 'std::unordered_map<_Kty,_Ty>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'TTT'  ...
```

where `DLLEXPORT` macro is in normal pattern, which is expand to `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` in the right place.

My question is: if put `DLLEXPORT` after this class declaration, the C4251 warning is gone, WHY?

```
class TTT
{
    unordered_map<int, int> _map;
};
class DLLEXPORT TTT;
```

Comment: As reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767579/exporting-classes-containing-std-objects-vector-map-etc-from-a-dll
Does your approach work? Can you use your class inside of another project as you expect it?

Comment: No warning because the class does not actually get exported.  Not a fix of course.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh, I think you are right.